# Нужно ли тире после "кажется"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли тире после слова "кажется"?

Её муж, кажется, – директор какой-то компании.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тире не ставится при наличии вводного слова: *Её муж, **кажется**, директор какой-то компании.*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92  § 5. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым  Пункт 1.

**Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится:

4. если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит **вводное слово**, иногда — наречие, союз, частица: **Дубава, кажется, друг Корчагина** (Н. О); Риск, как известно, дело благородное; Необдуманный поступок вообще шаг опасный; Сергеев теперь известный художник; Пихта тоже дерево смолистое; Март только начало весны.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133904/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).